# ggplot2 plotting two variables of two groups and with different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of following form:

```
School_type     Year    fund  rate  
    1           1998    8     0.1
    0           1998    7     0.2
    1           1999    9     0.11
    0           1999    8     0.22
    1           2000    10    0.12
    0           2000    15    0.23
```

I am thinking about plotting the "fund" and "rate" for each school type and the x axis is year, so there are four lines--two higher lines and two lower lines, but I don't know how to implement this with two scales of y-axes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

Comment: @JonSpring thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is my two cents on your question.

```
#create the dataframe
df = data.frame("school_type" = 0:1, "year" = c("1998","1998","1999","1999","2000","2000"), 
            "fund" = c("8","7","9","8","10","15"), "rate" = c("0.1","0.2","0.11","0.22","0.12","0.23"))

#Modify the variable typr
df$fund = as.numeric(as.character(df$fund))
df$rate = as.numeric(as.character(df$rate))

#plot the log of the variables
df %>%
mutate(log_fund = log(fund),
     log_rate = log(rate)) %>%
melt(id.vars = c("school_type","year")) %>%
filter(variable %in% c("log_fund","log_rate")) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = variable, color = variable, shape = variable)) +
geom_line(size = 1) +
geom_point(size = 3) +
facet_wrap(~ school_type) +
theme_bw()
```

Result: [image: here]